# Sending emails with "Name" <email> from Go

Tags: email, go, smtp, standard-library

I'm using `net/smtp` to send emails, which appears unable to handle contact names in emails.

```
c, _ := smtp.Dial("smtp.example.com:25")
c.Mail(`jdoe@example.com`)
```

rather than

```
c, _ := smtp.Dial("smtp.example.com:25")
c.Mail(`"John Q. Doe" <jdoe@example.com>`)
```

Is there a good way to handle this? I'd prefer something encapsulated and standard if available, but I'm willing to work with raw SMTP if that's all that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

can you try without the double quotes? ie

```
c.Mail(`John Q. Doe <jdoe@example.com>`)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. If you look at https://golang.org/src/net/smtp/smtp.go#L233 you can see they're already wrapping it, so `Mail` can't handle this at all.

Comment: Looks like you are right that you can't do it with the standard library, but I think they were trying to force only completely spec compliant code.  Copying and modifying smtp.go doesn't look very hard though.

Answer (score 0):

```
smtpServer := "smtp.example.com"
auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", "from@example.com", "******", smtpServer)

from := mail.Address{"fromName", "from@example.com"}
to := mail.Address{"toName", "to@example.com"}
msg := []byte("From: " + from.String() + "\r\n" +
"To: " + to.String() + "\r\n" +
"Subject: Awesome Subject !\r\n" +
"This is the email body.\r\n")
err := smtp.SendMail(smtpServer + ":25", auth, from.Address,[]string{to.Address}, msg)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```